# How do I create a rolling date filter in Power Query?

Tags: powerquery

Here is what I have:

```
Result = Table.SelectRows(
    #"Filtered Rows", 
    each [LATEST_ACCEPTABLE_DATE] 
        <= Date.AddDays(
            #date(DateTime.LocalNow(),17)
        )
    )
```

It returns:

> Expression.Error: 2 arguments were passed to a function which expects 3.

I'm not sure where it expects a 3rd argument....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't understand your code, consider formatting it properly:

```
Result = Table.SelectRows(
    #"Filtered Rows", 
    each [LATEST_ACCEPTABLE_DATE] 
        <= Date.AddDays(
            #date(DateTime.LocalNow(),17)
        )
)
```

Now you can easily see that you are using the #date() constructor with just 2 parameters instead of 3:

```
#date(year as number, month as number, day as number) as date
```

Actually, you don't need it here. Use instead:

```
Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())
```